# Separate multidimensional array into separate arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to get my head around arrays.

The arrays should look like this:

```
$questions[$a] => array( [0] => No, comment1
                         [1] => Yes, comment2
                         [2] => No, comment3 )

$answer[$a] => array( [0] => No
                      [1] => Yes
                      [3] => No )

$comment[$a] => array( [0] => comment1
                       [1] => comment2
                       [3] => comment3 )
```

**=========================================================================**

**SECOND EDIT:** Need to execute this in the loop to create a third array -

```
if($answer[$a] == "Yes") { $display[$a] = "style='display:none'"; 
} else { $display[$a] = "style='display:block'"; }
```

**This is what i have: (28th for minitech)**

```
while ($a > $count)
{
if($count > 11) {
foreach($questions as $q) {
    list($answer, $comments[]) = explode(',', $q);
    if($answer === "Yes") { 
    $display[$a] = "style='display:none'"; 
    } else { 
    $display[$a] = "style='display:block'"; 
    }

$answers[] = $answer;
    }
  }
$a++;
}
```

Comment: If they're actually strings separated by commas, that would be a problem. Try [`explode`](http://php.net/explode).

Comment: Sorry, i accepted a bit prematurely, i also need this code executed as part of the loop to create a third array... `if($answer[$a] == "Yes") { $display[$a] = "style='display:none'"; } else { $display[$a] = "style='display:block'"; }`

Comment: Okay, I added an answer.

Comment: you need to work on your premature acceptance...

Comment: @Raidenace: What does that even mean?

Comment: meant to be a laugh, buddy :)

Comment: havent got the jizzst of it yet ;)

Comment: haha but I think you have  ;-)

Comment: @sethO well spotted sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are actually strings, [`explode`](http://php.net/explode) works:

```
$answers = array();
$comments = array();
$display = array();

foreach(array_slice($questions, 11) as $question) {
    list($answer, $comments[]) = explode(',', $question);
    $display[] = $answer === 'Yes' ? 'style="display: none"' : 'style="display: block"';
    $answers[] = $answer;
}
```

[Here’s a demo!](http://codepad.viper-7.com/v9ZSv3)

Comment: ahh... ok gottcha, will give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify, how do i create the $display array with the above, i was counting $a like $display[$a] each iteration, do i define it as $display[] and just use $display for each iteration? Hope that makes sense!

Comment: @Edward: This replaces your inner loop, so it would still be `$display[$a]`.

Comment: Getting parse error unexpected "[". I am running PHP 5.2.17, i see codepad is set to 5.5, would this affect the result??

Comment: @Edward: Yup. Change `$answers = [];` to `$answers = array();` and do the same with `$comments`, and it should work. Also, consider upgrading ;)

Comment: Will talk to our server guy. :)

Comment: For some reason $q is returning null? Subsequently $answer and $comments are the same. 

`while ($a > $count)
{
if($count > 11) {
foreach($questions as $q) {
    list($answer, $comments[]) = explode(',', $q);
    if($answer === "Yes") { 
    $display[$a] = "style='display:none'"; 
    } else { 
    $display[$a] = "style='display:block'"; 
    }

$answers[] = $answer;
    }
  }
$a++;
}`

Comment: @Edward: How are you checking? Also, why are you checking `$count` inside the loop? That seems like a bug…

Comment: formatted better in the question ^^ the conditional is because the first 11 columns in the database aren't arrays.

Comment: Okay, so how are you checking that `$answer` is `null`?

Comment: Did you check `$answers`? The array is `$answers`, the intermediate variable is `$answer`.

Comment: ah. yes i did but i only get "array(0) { }" is that null? or is something lurking? $answer gives null.

Comment: @Edward: Maybe it ought to be `$answers[$a][] = $answer;` and `list($answer, $questions[$a][])`.

Comment: still returning null even with `var_dump($q);` `var_dump($questions);` returns 
`[11]=>
  string(11) "No, comment"
  [12]=>
  string(11) "No, comment"` etc...

Comment: @Edward: `$questions` is the source… could you maybe try to reproduce as much as possible in a [codepad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/)?

Comment: @Edward: Okay, there were a couple problems: a) wrong variable name b) missing `[]` c) `while($a > $count)` should have been `while($a < $count)` d) `$q` isn’t the right variable e) there should only be one loop. To sum up: http://codepad.viper-7.com/v9ZSv3

Comment: You should have seen my face when array slice appeared. hahaha, brilliant mate! Thank you so much, can you put that as the answer so i can accept?

Answer (score 0):

Change your while loop to this

```
while ...
{
$parts = explode(',', $questions[$a]);
$answer[$a][] = trim($parts[0]);
$comment[$a][] = trim($parts[1]);
}
```

In your original code you were overwriting the $answer[$a] and $comment[$a] each time, not appending to the end of an array

Comment: Modified slightly as I wasn't sure if you had done the split (also I missed a bracket in there )

Answer (score 0):

```
$questions[$a] = array('Q1?' => 'A1', 'Q2?' => 'A2', 'Q3?' => 'A3');

foreach($questions[$a] as $key => $value)
{
    $comment[$a][] = $key;
    $answer[$a][] = $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
foreach ($questions[$a] as $key=>$value){
  $temp = explode(',',$value);
  $answer[$key] = $temp[0];
  $comment[$key] = $temp[1];
}
```

$key will have 0,1,2 respectively. $value will have the values for each $question[$a](No,Comment1 ....)

Answer (score 0):

Can't think of a funky one-liner, but this should do it:

```
foreach ($questions as $a => $entries) {
    foreach ($entries as $k => $entry) {
        $parts = array_map('trim', explode(',', $entry));
        $answer[$a][$k] = $parts[0];
        $comment[$a][$k] = $parts[1];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the right answer

```
foreach($questions as $key => $question){
  foreach($question as $q => $data){
   $data= explode(',',$data);
   $comments[$key][$q] = $data[0];
   $answer[$key][$q] = $data[1];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the values in `$questions` are comma-separated strings you could use an `array_walk` function to populate your `$answer` and `$comment` arrays

```
$question = array(...); //array storing values as described
$answer = array();
$comment = array();

array_walk($question, function ($value, $key) use ($answer,$comment) {
    $value_array = explode(',', $value);
    $answer[$key] = $value_array[0];
    $comment[$key] = $value_array[1];
});
```

Note that this is shown using an anonymous function (closure) which requires PHP >= 5.3.0.  If you had a lower version of PHP, you would need to declare a named function, and declare $answer and $comment as globals in the function.  I think this is a hacky approach (using globals like this) so if I was using PHP < 5.3 I would probably just use a foreach loop like other answers to your question propose.

Functions like `array_walk`, `array_filter` and similar functions where callbacks are used are often great places to leverage the flexibility provided by anonymous functions.

Comment: 5.2 :( thanks for the example tho, will bear it in mind if we upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

```
$questions = array( 0 => 'No,comment1',1 => 'Yes,comment2',2 => 'No,comment3' );

foreach($questions as $question)
{
    $parts = explode(",",$question);
    $answer[] = $parts[0];
    $comment[] = $parts[1]; 
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($answer);
print_r($comment);
```